# ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Malformed version number string “4.0”) during validation

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm updating my pod library on cocoapods. but on Validate this by the following command

`pod lib lint`

i'm facing the following error :

```
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Malformed version number string “4.0”) during validation.
```

I tried all, but nothing found usable. Please guide.

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint myPod.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'myPod'
  s.version          = '0.2.1'
  s.summary          = 'A collection of toolset for image operations.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC

  A collection of toolset for image operations.

  1. Create Gif from images
  2. Create Video from images with background audio.
  3. Boomrang.
  4. Collage.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://git.mycompany.com/mycompany/editor'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Mohit' => 'mohit.tomar@mycompany.ai' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://git.mycompany.com/mycompany/editor.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'



  s.source_files = 'myPod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resources = ['myPod/Assets/*']

  #s.resource_bundles = {
  # 'myPod' => ['myPod/Assets/*']
  #}

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  # s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Comment: @Anand i'm updating my own cocoapod. not the pods in a project.

Comment: I meant your podspec only. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have faced the same issue earlier while working with old cocoapod version. For me, update to the latest version is worked!

Comment: Can you share your .podspec file? And I am expecting that you have pushed the '4.0' tag to your pod repo.